# Gunicorn Settings for multisite hosting

Tags: linux, django, gunicorn

I am having hard time executing gunicorn within virtual env and following are my settings as I am getting Linux access error for folder. I am new to Linux so please advise. Error can be seen below settings:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="myproject"                                                # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/django/myproject                                         # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/django/run/gunicorn.sock                              # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=django                                                     # the user to run as
GROUP=django                                                    # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                                   # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings                       # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=myproject.wsgi:application                    # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

Error:

```
(myproject)django@vps:~/myproject$ bin/gunicorn_start.sh
Starting: command not found
(myproject)django@vps:~/myproject$ bin/gunicorn_start.sh: line 15: cd: /django/myproject: No such file or directory
-su: bin/gunicorn_start.sh:: No such file or directory
(myproject)django@vps:~/myproject$ bin/gunicorn_start.sh: line 16: ../bin/activate: No such file or directory
-su: bin/gunicorn_start.sh:: No such file or directory
(myproject)django@vps:~/myproject$ mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/django’: Permission denied
No command 'mkdir:' found, did you mean:
 Command 'mkdir' from package 'coreutils' (main)
mkdir:: command not found
(myproject)django@vps:~/myproject$ bin/gunicorn_start.sh: line 26: /home/django/myproject/../bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
```

I am following [link](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) to configure startup script and I've created a user "django".

after I've changed my "DJANGODIR" to /home/Django/myproject I am getting these two errors now.

```
(myproject)django@vps:~/myproject$ bin/gunicorn_start.sh
Starting myproject as django
bin/gunicorn_start.sh: line 16: ../bin/activate: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/django’: Permission denied
bin/gunicorn_start.sh: line 26: /home/django/myproject/../bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
(myproject)django@vps:~/myproject$
```

I've changed 4 lines in my gunicorn upstart script to full path like:

```
DJANGODIR=/home/django/myproject
SOCKFILE=/home/django/myproject/run/gunicorn.sock
source /home/django/myproject/bin/activate
exec /home/django/myproject/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
```

There was an extra "application" argument and I was getting error for that. I've removed the application in line four above and I was able to run the script. Now gunicorn is running but I can't get the project live as myproject.com is not showing up. How do I bind a port within this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I'm about to give you is based off an assumption, I think your `$DJANGODIR` is supposed to be `/home/django/myproject` but you have it pointed to `/django/myproject` which belongs to root, which is why your program can't create the folder.

If my assumption isn't right, please post where you have your files located and their permissions. you can use `ls -l filename` to get the permissions of a file and `ls -ld directory` to get the permissions of a directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My Django user has full rights/permissions on the folder I've created and location is /home/Django/myproject. One of the project under same user but without any virtualenv is working fine. I am actually using DigitalOceanOne click installation image and my folder permissions and file locations are exactly as https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image. I've pasted the result of changes in original question.

Comment: it turns out that full path based settings made gunicorn run and I was able to make things work for now. Thanks for help.